# Forgot password for VS Project pfx file

Tags: visual-studio, signing, pfx

I'm trying to work on an old Visual Studio 2010 project from another computer, but I forgot the password for the pfx file used to sign the assembly.  Is it possible to crack the password or is there a way to build the project without knowing the password?

Comment: You can export the PFX certificate from the certificate store, if the private key has been marked exportable when the pfx was installed.

Answer (score 8):

If you remember certain characteristics about your password (i.e. starts with 'pass', does not contain tilde, ampersand, digits 6 - 9, etc...) you could use [this utility](http://boredwookie.net/index.php/blog/certificate-password-recovery-tool/) (boredwookie.net) I wrote to help you recover the password. It is released under an Open Source (MIT) License so you can see how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had a 6 digit PIN and it was recovered after 15 minutes. I simply used the windows executable in the bin/Releases folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new key to sign the assembly with.
1) Open the project.

2) Right click the project name in solution explorer and click properties.

3) On the Signing tab where it says "Choose a strong name key file:", select "New.."

4) Use the dialog window to create a new key file and password encode it with something you can remember.

Comment: I did this but when I publish it gives error "Clickonce does not support the request execution level requestAdministrator

Answer (score 1):

Open the project file in Notepad. Find the signtool.exe command line. It's the string after the /p switch...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a new one? You might be able to crack the password but if you arent using it in other projects it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

This was an old project and the author was gone.  I just made sure the sign the assembly was unchecked and the I deleted any pfx files in the project.